# How to find the boundaries of integration?

Tags: calculus

I have to compute the  integral w $\int \int \int_{S} x dV$ where S is the portion in the first octant above the plane $z=x+y-1$ and below $z=1$. I was wondering what was the region of integration in the $xy$ plane. I think its the region in the first quadrant $1 \leq x+y \leq 2$, but it also makes sense to me to consider the region $0 \leq x+y \leq 2$. Any hints?

Comment: Your first inequality is correct. The region in the plane $z=0$ is a parallelogram, not a triangle. It is bounded below by the line $y=1-x$, above by the line $y=2-x$ and by the lines $x=0$ and $y=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! Just a small correction the region is a trapezoid not a parallelogram.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, it is a trapezoid. My bad. Notice that if you take cross sections of the resulting solid in the planes $x+y=t$ for $0\le t\le1$, that is, planes parallel to planes $x+y=1$ and $x+y=2$ then the cross sections are rectangles with height $t$ and width $(1+t)\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Oops, this is not a volume problem. Now I see you have $x\,dV$, not $dV$.